# make lucene into full fledged search engine like google

Tags: lucene, search-engine

i wanted to build a search engine like google where if i enter a search term it retrieves the urls to websites.
i used lucene with tomcat but it searches the files residing in my system.

i want to search throughout the web.Please tell me how to do this using lucene?
if we can't do this using lucene,please suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Nutch.](http://nutch.apache.org/about.html)